# php.ini is nonexistent Loaded Configuration File (none)

Tags: php, linux

I have compiled php and apache successfully, without specifying the directory for the php config file. I want to add pear features, but there doesn't appear to be a php.ini anywhere.
In my phpinfo, it says

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /usr/local/apache2/php/lib
>   Loaded Configuration File   (none)
>   Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
>   Additional .ini files parsed    (none)

I went to the /usr/local/apache2/php/lib directory, and there was, indeed nothing there. I also searched for php.ini, and didn't get any results whatsoever. I need to change things in php.ini, and I don't know how php is even working without one. I am just wondering whether I need to recompile php with a config directory, and how to find/acquire a php.ini so that I can fix some things.

Comment: Did you restart httpd after compiling and installing php?

Comment: @MikePurcell Yes, several times.

Comment: Can you post your configure command?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to copy the file `php.ini-dist` from PHP source. Standard way is copying such file to `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`.

Comment: Where can I find php.ini-dist exactly?

Comment: @Black In [php_src](https://github.com/php/php-src), there are `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` files. Use one of those.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that you compiled php without the --with-config-file-path=PATH option.

Try to reconfigure php using this option. Then run "make clean", "make" and "make install" again in this order. You must run "make clean" for this to work.

Comment: I was thinking this as well, but the fact that PHP is reporting back with a path at all leads me to believe this may not be the issue.

Comment: @MikePurcell That is what I was thinking as well, that's why I wasn't going to do it before posting my question. I wanted a more official opinion on whether I should. Compiling now, will report back my results shortly.

Comment: Didn't work, I did the same thing with that in the configure, and nothing happened. It stayed exactly as it was before. I ran make clean and everything.

Comment: what path did you put when reconfiguring? Does phpinfo() path of php changed? have you tryed just to copy php.ini of your version from http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/?

Comment: I tried exactly like you described but `php -i | grep -i loaded` still returns `Loaded Configuration File => (none)`

Answer (score 7):

first check is there  `/etc/php.ini` exists , if no try to copy it

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

check it again with `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`, if still is none try to

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

then reload the webserver and try to see result with

```
php --ini
```

Answer (score 2):

I went through this recently with a freshly installed PHP8.1. The permissions on the /usr/local/etc/8.1 directory were set to root blocking homebrew from completing the install properly which includes generating the configuration files. This caused Nginx to error with a 502 cause valet.sock doesn't work without PHP properly installed.

I set the permissions on the directory back to my user using chown command than did

```
brew remove php@8.1

brew install php@8.1 --build-from-source

brew link php@8.1
```

Everything was working again and my local sites were coming up like normal.

Answer (score 0):

`ini` file must end with `.ini` and not `php.ini-dist`. Remove the `-dist` as it looks like a notepad file (in Windows) and cannot be read by the system.
Restart Apache and check you phpinfo() output.