# MySQLi installed but didn't enable

Tags: mysqli

guys

I've intalled the mysqli.so from the source:

```
[root@li460-123 no-debug-non-zts-20090626]# pwd
/usr/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
[root@li460-123 no-debug-non-zts-20090626]# ls
mysqli.so  pdo_mysql.so
[root@li460-123 no-debug-non-zts-20090626]#
```

And then i enable it in /php-install-2/etc/php.ini (where my php installed):

```
extension=/usr/lib64/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mysqli.so
```

Then i restart my nginx server but the phpinfo didn't show MySQLi.

```
[http://sobugou.com/phpinfo.php][1]
```

My php is installed at

```
[root@li460-123 php-install-2]# pwd
/disk1/php-install-2
[root@li460-123 php-install-2]# ls
bin  etc  include  lib  man  sbin  share  var
[root@li460-123 php-install-2]# cd etc/
[root@li460-123 etc]# ls
php-fpm.conf  php-fpm.conf.default  php.ini
[root@li460-123 etc]#
```

Could anyone help ? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at http://sobugou.com/phpinfo.php, you can see `Loaded Configuration File` is set to `(none)`. This means that your php.ini configuration file is not being used. Problem can be fixed using `--with-config-file-path=PATH` flag during PHP compilation.

See more: [php.ini is nonexistent Loaded Configuration File (none)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711698/php-ini-is-nonexistent-loaded-configuration-file-none)