# PHP 7.0.1 couldn't load ini file

Tags: php, php-7

File exist in path, but php couldn't load ini file.
What I try - change chmod, chown, change configuration path. No results.

```
# /opt/php7/bin/php -i
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.0.1

System => Linux portal-app 3.8.13-68.1.3.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Wed Apr 22 11:51:54 PDT 2015 x86_64
Build Date => Dec 18 2015 10:01:55
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/opt/php7' '--exec- prefix=/opt/php7' '--enable-fpm' '--with-fpm-user=user' '--with-fpm-group=nginx' '--disable-cgi' '--disable-short-tags' '--with-openssl' '--with-zlib' '--with-curl' '--with-snmp' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir' '--with-png-dir' '--with-zlib-dir' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-freetype-dir' '--with-gettext' '--enable-exif' '--enable-intl' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-zip' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-imap=/opt/distrib/php7/ext/imap-2007f' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-ldap' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-soap' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pdo-pgsql' '--with-pgsql' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-fpm-systemd'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/php7/lib
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20151012
PHP Extension => 20151012
Zend Extension => 320151012

# ls -la /opt/php7/lib
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 дек  8 09:24 php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 php  nginx  760 дек 18 10:12 php.ini
```

Comment: what is the output of `ls -Z` have you checked selinux logs?

Comment: hmmm no idea then. but one thing i noticed is you don't need execute permission for php.ini.

Comment: Change permissions to 0755, no results :(

Comment: it should be `0644` but i don't think that can be the problem. just mentioning because i have seen in one server where any file with execute permission was not read into configuration

Comment: if you reference it manually with `php -c /opt/php7/lib/php.ini` does it work?

Comment: Yes, with -c directive all works fine.

Comment: the php.ini is the ini distributed with php7?

Comment: No, custom. File is correct, with -c all is ok.

Comment: did you see this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711698/php-ini-is-nonexistent-loaded-configuration-file-none .. they suggest doing a `make clean` but not sure why that would matter

Comment: does it give you the same result if you load it through your web server?  what about if you do `PHP_INI_PATH=/opt/php7/lib/ php -i`?

Comment: if you compile with `--with-config-file-path=/opt/php7/lib --sysconfdir=/opt/php7/lib` does it work?  in my php it references those 2 configure parameters and paths explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, settting with-config-file-path and make clean my resolve problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strace helped me to find the problem.

```
# echo "<?php phpinfo() ?>" | strace /opt/php7/bin/php  2>&1 | grep php.ini
open("/etc/php7/php.ini/php-cli.ini", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
open("/opt/php7/bin/php.ini", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/php7/php.ini/php.ini", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
```

I do not understand why, but PHP is looking in the wrong folder. It seems that the change `with-config-file-path` without `make clean` causes to the problem.

I added `--with-config-file-path=/opt/php7/lib` to `./configure` and executed `make clean && make && make install`.

It solved the problem.

Comment: I found the same: `/etc/php7` would not work, but `/etc/php7/cli` did. Not sure if it is the `make clean` or the extra level of directory. Thanks, in any case!