Setting up mail for PHP in a Docker container
I'm trying to get my PHP container to send emails.
Both here and here it is mentioned that the configuration setting should be in the php.ini file.
However, when I put a phpinfo() somewhere in my code, this is what I see:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path           /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File                   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed                /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-fpm.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-exif.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gettext.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gmp.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-memcached.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-yaml.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/newrelic.ini 

I'm running my PHP project inside a Docker container.
Here's the Dockerfile (a bit simplified):
FROM composer:2 as vendor

COPY public/composer.json composer.json

RUN composer clearcache

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist && \
    composer dumpautoload --optimize

FROM php:8.3-fpm-alpine3.19

EXPOSE 80

RUN pecl install xdebug && \
   docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

COPY config/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

COPY public /var/www/repo/public

# install dependencies
COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /var/www/repo/public/vendor/
RUN chown -R www-data /var/www/repo/public/vendor/

WORKDIR /var/www
CMD ["/var/www/repo/scripts/start"]

This is all fine, the container builds and the app runs fine (apart from the fact that it's not sending emails):
function _mail(
    string $to,
    string $subject,
    string $message,
    string $headers = '',
    string $params = ''
): void {
    if (!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $params)) {
        throw new Exception('Something went wrong when sending email');
    }
}

When I run this, it always end up inside the if and throwing that exception, and I can't figure out why. The fact that PHP's mail() function is notoriously hard to debug doesn't help either (I've already read many SO questions about it, and I'm aware that using for example error_get_last() doesn't help).
As you can see, I am already adding an extra .ini file for my Xdebug config.
Do I need to do something similar for the mail configuration?
If so, how should that file be called and what should it contain?

Yes, you need to load extensions in order to use them. The base image is intentionally rather minimal.

By not sending email you mean it throws error that mail function does not exist or something else? Are you using PHPMailer? mail function usually is unreliable and you can find plenty of question regarding it not sending emails

You could also put it all in one config file it does not matter. Separating configs is just for orgnaization. You could also mount your config files as volumes then you dont have to rebuild everytime you change something.

@Justinas it means that mail just doesn't do anything. It returns falsebut I don't know why. I edited the question to add that.

Than look at why that fails, not how to enable default extension. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786221/mail-returns-false

@Justinas the question you linked mentions the php.ini, which I cannot find in my project. I think part of the problem is that my SMTP settings are wrong or non existing, and I don't know where/how to fix them. As you can see, the question is actually about that, not about "enabling default extension". I don't know where you got that from.

Also I see that there is Loaded Configuration File (none). Try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711698/php-ini-is-nonexistent-loaded-configuration-file-none

Trying to do SMTP using mail() wont work. You cannot pass the password, So you may have to install a mail server and configure PHP to see the mail server in this container, or if it possible a seperate mail container.

The PHP mail() function works by calling out to a system binary with default parameters defined by the ini config sendmail_path - so usually /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i - and passing the e-mail on stdin.
You can set/change this in any php.ini that is loaded - which in your container is any *.ini file in /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/. So you can just drop a new file there with your desired configuration like you already did for xdebug.

But be aware that this then obviously also requires the configured binary to be installed within the container, i.e., sendmail.
sendmail on the other hand must be properly configured to relay the passed e-mails to a mail transfer agent. It is usually installed together with an MTA like postfix to which it then delivers the mails locally.
This would then mean you'd had to run an MTA in the container, too - which is most probably something you don't want.
Instead you could rather use a sendmail alternative that can be configured to directly forward the e-mails to another server via SMTP, e.g., msmtp.

This may sound needlessly complex - and it is.
In the end it might be a better solution to use a proper mailing library for PHP which supports using SMTP servers directly - like the symfony/mailer.

+1 for the SMTP server suggestion. Most users' email providers (e.g. Gmail, Outlook) will look for DKIM signatures on the headers in incoming email and will silently route them to spam if they're missing. Using an email service (e.g. Mailchimp) instead of sendmail ensures the DKIM signatures are present instead of having to worry about setting them. You can configure sendmail to set them, but it's a ball-ache. In general, configuring sendmail is a ball-ache.

Note that sending email out directly may sometimes fail (network issue, upstream server is down, etc). Either you have to implement retry logic in your PHP application, or you can use a proper MTA that will handle retrying for you. msmtp will not do that, but nullmailer will, which is a tiny forward-only MTA.
